# apply css to a single textbox using jQuery addClass OR a custom LoadCSS function

Tags: jquery, css, django

I am using Django and I want to apply some css to a single textbox. I used the website enjoycss.com to create some css. I have then added this css to the end of Django's base.css:

```
.disabledInput {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 6px solid #36c40f;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: normal normal bold 15px/normal Georgia, serif;
  color: rgba(0,142,198,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: rgba(252,252,252,1);
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -o-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
```

I have a javascript function that I have verified works, using something like this, that has nothing to do with the stylesheet:

```
$(this).css("background", green);
```

But if I comment that out and try to use this, it does not work:

```
$(this).addClass("disabledInput");
```

Why?

In addition, I have created the same .disabledInput all by itself in its own css file named disabled.css. Then, I have tried adding that css file to the textbox attributes, like this:

```
$(this).loadCSS('admin/css/disabled.css');
```

The LoadCSS function looks like this:

```
$.fn.loadCSS = function(url) {
    if (!$('link[href="' + url + '"]').length)
        $(this).append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + url + '">');
```

}

Why doesn't it work? What am I overlooking?

Comment: With regard to the first point, it's possible that the `disabledInput` class is being added but the rules are being overridden by another CSS selector with high precedence. Use the DOM inspector to check this.

Comment: On your second point, when you say 'it doesn't work' do you mean that the `<link />` element is not inserted in to the DOM, or that the styles aren't applied? Again, have you checked the DOM to ensure the content has been added, and the console to see if there is any errors

Comment: on the first point, the class shows as this: class="vDateField disabledInput". So, vDateField must be taking precedence over disabledInput Rory McCrossan

Comment: on the second point, I do not see any <link /> element being inserted. I am searching for the solution...

Comment: I added this: $(this).removeClass("vDateField").addClass("disabledInput");. It changed class="vDateField disabledInput" to class="disabledInput", but the style is still not applied.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing all the right things, so without seeing the problem reproduced we cannot really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a cached file issue. In specific:

Did not work:

- flush the cache in PyCharm using the Invalidate Cache and Restart command.
- use Apple Automator scripts to flush the caches of Safari and Chrome

Worked:

- Going into Safari to manually Clear History.
- Downloading Cache Killer for Chrome